# How to find connected nodes of a selected node in D3js Tidy tree chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a Tidy Tree chart like this

```js
const data = {
  "name": "tree",
  "children": [{
    "name": "A",
    "children": [{
        "name": "B",
        "children": [{
          "name": "C",
          "size": 3938
        }, ]
      },
      {
        "name": "H",
        "children": [{
            "name": "D",
            "size": 3534
          },
          {
            "name": "E",
            "size": 5731
          },
          {
            "name": "F",
            "size": 7840
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }]
}

const width = 928;

// Compute the tree height; this approach will allow the height of the
// SVG to scale according to the breadth (width) of the tree layout.
const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
const dx = 10;
const dy = width / (root.height + 1);

// Create a tree layout.
const tree = d3.tree().nodeSize([dx, dy]);

// Sort the tree and apply the layout.
root.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.data.name, b.data.name));
tree(root);

// Compute the extent of the tree. Note that x and y are swapped here
// because in the tree layout, x is the breadth, but when displayed, the
// tree extends right rather than down.
let x0 = Infinity;
let x1 = -x0;
root.each(d => {
  if (d.x > x1) x1 = d.x;
  if (d.x < x0) x0 = d.x;
});

// Compute the adjusted height of the tree.
const height = x1 - x0 + dx * 2;

const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("viewBox", [-dy / 3, x0 - dx, width, height])
  .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; font: 10px sans-serif;");

const link = svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#555")
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.4)
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)

link
  .selectAll()
  .data(root.links())
  .join("path")
  .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
    .x(d => d.y)
    .y(d => d.x));

const node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .selectAll()
  .data(root.descendants())
  .join("g")
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`)

node.append("circle")
  .attr("fill", d => d.children ? "#555" : "#999")
  .attr("r", 5.5)

node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", "0.31em")
  .attr("x", d => d.children ? -6 : 6)
  .attr("text-anchor", d => d.children ? "end" : "start")
  .text(d => d.data.name)
  .clone(true).lower()
  .attr("stroke", "white");

d3.selectAll("circle").on("contextmenu", (event) => {
  this.selectedNode = event.srcElement.__data__.data
});

const connectNodes = (t, f) => {
  let to = null,
    fr = null;
  node.each(d => {
    if (d.data.name === t) to = d;
    if (d.data.name === f) fr = d;
  });
  if (to && fr) {
    link.append("path")
      .attr("d", "M" + to.y + "," + to.x + "L" + fr.y + "," + fr.x)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "red");
  }
};
connectNodes("B", "D");
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

and I wanna to find know list of connected nodes of **node B**
[image]
here it would be **A** , **C** and **D**

how can I do it ?

Comment: Wouldn't the connected nodes of 'B' be 'C' and 'D' or 'A', 'C', and 'D' if you consider inverse connections?

Comment: it would be A ,C and D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to modify your code and add ID to path:

---

you add ID here:

```
link
  .selectAll()
  .data(root.links())
  .join("path")
  .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
    .x(d => d.y)
    .y(d => d.x))
    .attr("id", d =>
        d.source.data.name + "-" + d.target.data.name
    );
```

---

and in your function connectNodes:

```
const connectNodes = (t, f) => {
  let to = null,
    fr = null;
  node.each(d => {
    if (d.data.name === t) to = d;
    if (d.data.name === f) fr = d;
  });
  if (to && fr) {
    link.append("path")
      .attr("d", "M" + to.y + "," + to.x + "L" + fr.y + "," + fr.x)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("id", d =>
        t + "-" + f
    );
  }
};
```

---

New function to get links:

```
getLinks = (z) => {
  const regex = new RegExp('-*' + z + '-*');
  const cids = document.querySelectorAll("svg g path[id$='-" + z + "'], svg g path[id^='" + z + "-']");

  return Array.from(cids).map((i) => i.id.replace(regex, ""));
};

console.log(getLinks("B"));
```

a variant with d3:

```
getLinks = (z) => {
  const regex = new RegExp('-*' + z + '-*');
  const cids = d3.selectAll("svg g path[id$='-" + z + "'], svg g path[id^='" + z + "-']").nodes().map(element => element.id.replace(regex, ""));
    return cids;
};
```

```js
const data = {
  "name": "tree",
  "children": [{
    "name": "A",
    "children": [{
        "name": "B",
        "children": [{
          "name": "C",
          "size": 3938
        }, ]
      },
      {
        "name": "H",
        "children": [{
            "name": "D",
            "size": 3534
          },
          {
            "name": "E",
            "size": 5731
          },
          {
            "name": "F",
            "size": 7840
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }]
}

const width = 928;

// Compute the tree height; this approach will allow the height of the
// SVG to scale according to the breadth (width) of the tree layout.
const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
const dx = 10;
const dy = width / (root.height + 1);

// Create a tree layout.
const tree = d3.tree().nodeSize([dx, dy]);

// Sort the tree and apply the layout.
root.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.data.name, b.data.name));
tree(root);

// Compute the extent of the tree. Note that x and y are swapped here
// because in the tree layout, x is the breadth, but when displayed, the
// tree extends right rather than down.
let x0 = Infinity;
let x1 = -x0;
root.each(d => {
  if (d.x > x1) x1 = d.x;
  if (d.x < x0) x0 = d.x;
});

// Compute the adjusted height of the tree.
const height = x1 - x0 + dx * 2;

const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("viewBox", [-dy / 3, x0 - dx, width, height])
  .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; font: 10px sans-serif;");

const link = svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#555")
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.4)
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)

link
  .selectAll()
  .data(root.links())
  .join("path")
  .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
    .x(d => d.y)
    .y(d => d.x))
    .attr("id", d =>
        d.source.data.name + "-" + d.target.data.name
    );

const node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .selectAll()
  .data(root.descendants())
  .join("g")
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`)

node.append("circle")
  .attr("fill", d => d.children ? "#555" : "#999")
  .attr("r", 5.5)

node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", "0.31em")
  .attr("x", d => d.children ? -6 : 6)
  .attr("text-anchor", d => d.children ? "end" : "start")
  .text(d => d.data.name)
  .clone(true).lower()
  .attr("stroke", "white");

d3.selectAll("circle").on("contextmenu", (event) => {
  this.selectedNode = event.srcElement.__data__.data
});

const connectNodes = (t, f) => {
  let to = null,
    fr = null;
  node.each(d => {
    if (d.data.name === t) to = d;
    if (d.data.name === f) fr = d;
  });
  if (to && fr) {
    link.append("path")
      .attr("d", "M" + to.y + "," + to.x + "L" + fr.y + "," + fr.x)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("id", d =>
        t + "-" + f
    );
  }
};
connectNodes("B", "D");

getLinks = (z) => {
  const regex = new RegExp('-*' + z + '-*');
  const cids = document.querySelectorAll("svg g path[id$='-" + z + "'], svg g path[id^='" + z + "-']");

  return Array.from(cids).map((i) => i.id.replace(regex, ""));
};

console.log(getLinks("B"));
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg></svg>
</body>

</html>
```